# Missing Datasource Configuration when trying to download a file

Tags: cakephp

In my UploadsController I have this download method:

```
function download($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $upload = $this->Upload->findById($id);
    if (!$upload) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }


    $path = APP . 'useruploads' . DS . $upload['Upload']['id'];
    $this->response->file($path);
    //Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

But when trying to download a file I get this error:

> Error: The datasource configuration 493 was not found in database.php.

The file exists, I checked. What does the database.php have to do with file download? This error message does not really make sense to me.

I'm using Cake 2.4.1. Can anyone tell me how their file download works with 2.4.1?

Here is the Stack Trace if that helps:

[image: stack trace]

What I found out:
My file is named 5262ffbf-6e44-45b8-abc6-0de8009d1f70.
Using $path2 in the file function will give me an error.
Using $path with the hardcoded ID works.
But the debug output of $path and $path2 is the same. How is this possible?

```
    $path = APP . 'useruploads' . DS . '5262ffbf-6e44-45b8-abc6-0de8009d1f70';
    $path2 = APP . 'useruploads' . DS . $upload['Upload']['id'];
    debug($path);
    debug($path2);
    $this->response->file($path2, array('download' => true, 'name' => 'logo.png'));
```

Comment: You dont' need to return the response object, a simple `$this->autoRender = false` would suffice. By the way.

Comment: Thanks, but it still won't work.
I really do not understand why the method with $path works and with $path2 it does not. It should be the same and the debug output even says so.

Comment: Obviously they are either not equal, or there is something else causing the problem. When using the hard coded path, is the rest of the code still _exactly_ the same? According to the stacktrace you are using the `Media` view, you shouldn't do that! Also it should actually only be invoked in case the controller actions response is not an instance of `CakeResponse`. Please show the expanded stacktrace that shows the context and scope data (and please left align the text) in case not using the `Media` view doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: The stacktrace also shows that the magic `Model::__call()` method is invoked on line 399 in `File.php`, which seems pretty weird to me, the only way I could see this happening is when the `File::$Folder` property would be a `Model` instance o_O

Comment: I used a self created Model named "Folder". Which turned out should not be possible as it broke everything it seems.
I renamed the Model to "Dir" and now it works

Answer (score 0):

I used a self created Model named "Folder". Which turned out should not be possible as it broke everything. I renamed the Model to "Dir" and now it works.
Should have read the list of protected Model names earlier.